# JAXB marshalling and unmarshalling CDATA

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, cdata

I have a requirement in which i have XML like this

```
<programs>
   <program>
      <name>test1</name>
      <instr><![CDATA[ some string ]]></instr>
   </program>
   <program>
      <name>test2</name> 
      <instr><![CDATA[ some string ]]></instr>
   </program>
</programs>
```

My program needs to unmarshal this to JAXB, do some processing and finally marshall back to xml. When I finally marshall the JAXB objects to xml, i get the  as plain text without CDATA prefix. But to keep the xml intact I need to get the xml back with CDATA prefix. It seems JAXB doesnt suppor this directly. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

CDATA or not, this should not be a problem since the output from JAXB will be escaped if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had the same problem and while looking in SO I found this post. Since I'm generating my beans with xjc I did not want to add a @XmlCData in the generated code.

After looking a while for a good solution I finally found this post: http://javacoalface.blogspot.pt/2012/09/outputting-cdata-sections-with-jaxb.html

Which contains the following example code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document document = 
docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

// Marshall the feed object into the empty document.
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(jaxbObject, document);

// Transform the DOM to the output stream
// TransformerFactory is not thread-safe
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = 
TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer nullTransformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
nullTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
nullTransformer.setOutputProperty(
OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS,
 "myElement myOtherElement");
nullTransformer.transform(new DOMSource(document),
 new StreamResult(writer));
```

It works pretty fine for me. Hope it helps others that land in this page looking for the same thing I was.

Comment: Works like a charm! IMHO best choice as it doesn't require MOXy and injects CDATA in specified elements (instead of custom-serializer-kind of solutions). @YMomb: JAXB will escape any XML content in strings, but sometimes you prefer to have xml-formatted string inside tag so it can be easily copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

You can use MOXy's `@XmlCDATA` extension to force a text node to be wrapped with CDATA:

```
package blog.cdata;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlCDATA;

@XmlRootElement(name="c")
public class Customer {

   private String bio;

   @XmlCDATA
   public void setBio(String bio) {
      this.bio = bio;
   }

   public String getBio() {
      return bio;
   }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I would like to stick with default implementation of JAXB. One that comes close to solve this problem is in http://jaxb.java.net/faq/JaxbCDATASample.java. But XMLSerializer has been deprecated and need to find an alternative.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan I use MOXy 2.1.2 and tha XmlCDATA is unknown. I use 4 JARs on my classpath for MOXy: `org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.1.2.jar , org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.1.2.jar , org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.1.2.jar , org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.1.2.jar`

Comment: @basZero - The `@XmlCDATA` was added in EclipseLink MOXy 2.2.  The current version is 2.4.1.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan as of your experience, is an upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.2 feasible without any adjustments?

Comment: @basZero - Yes, should just be a drop in replacement.

Comment: Thanks @BlaiseDoughan, but the download page for 2.2.1 does not work: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.2.1.php . And also: instead of adding the large `eclipselink.jar`, is there a way to just add a few `JARs` (like you told me for 2.1.2) in order to use only the MOXy ?

Comment: @basZero - You can get the bundles at this link:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/previous_releases.php

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan thanks! the outdated page I found should be removed somehow, but I don't know who manages all that.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan just fyi: starting at page http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/ you don't find the earlier releases. Links end on 404 pages.